# How do I run a mysql query in wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

This query works and returns the results that I want in MySQL but how do I get this to work in wordpress?

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'points' AND `user_id` = '1'
```

I want to be able to see all the 'points' earned by user 1. I need to be able to display this on posts and pages in wordpress.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'points' AND user_id = '1'");
print_r($result);
```

Read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries).

Comment: That article talks about making a plugin. I don't want to make a plugin just add some lines of code that will make the result appear on a page or post. I use the plugin Allow PHP in Post and Pages to add the php query code into. Is there another/easier way?

Comment: You can try add `global $wpdb;` before query code. It need to help, but I didn't try. I updated the code.

Comment: This is what shows up on the page when I enter your code above into the "add php plugin": Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [umeta_id] => 38 [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => points [meta_value] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [umeta_id] => 39 [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => points [meta_value] => 100 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [umeta_id] => 40 [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => points [meta_value] => 66 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [umeta_id] => 41 [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => points [meta_value] => 32 ) etc...

Comment: I want to be able to add all the values up. I'm guessing I use Select SUM * From...
When I do, I just get: array ( ) on my page

Comment: ok I got pretty close. I used: global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'points' AND `user_id` = '1'");
print_r($result);

and got:
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [SUM(meta_value)] => 615 ) )

I just want the number 615. How do I get ride of the other stuff on that line.

Comment: @user3030176 replace `SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM` with `SELECT SUM(meta_value) AS sum FROM` and do `echo $result[0]->sum;`

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the help. Now I need to be able to switch user_id='1' to current_user assuming that person is logged in. I tried this code here: if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(meta_value) AS sum FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'points' AND `user_id` = '$current_user'");
echo $result[0]->sum;
but got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /homepages/8/d195441424/htdocs/test/wp-content/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/allowphp.php(373) : eval()'d code on line 5

Comment: You forgot to close `{`

Comment: ok I added that } at the end. Is that correct? I get this error now: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_User could not be converted to string in /homepages/8/d195441424/htdocs/test/wp-content/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/allowphp.php(373) : eval()'d code on line 4

Comment: I ended up getting some additional help and got it working. Thank you for all your help. Here is the code that worked for me: if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(meta_value) AS sum FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'points' AND user_id = " . $current_user->ID);
echo $result[0]->sum;}?>

Comment: This is wrong and unsafe. It must use prepare statement, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Answer (score 2):

Use following code.....

```
$q="SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'points' AND user_id = '1'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($q);
```

It will return  array as result.

Comment: where can I even type this in though? I have a plugin called "Allow PHP in Post and Pages" and I tried the code there. This is the error it gives me: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in /homepages/8/d195441424/htdocs/test/wp-content/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/allowphp.php(373) : eval()'d code on line 2

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0):

You should try following code :

```
global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'points' AND user_id = '1'");
print_r($result);
```

Hope it will helpful.

Comment: usually the `prefix` already contains the trailing `_`

Comment: @DiegoBetto you are right, let me update the answer.