# How to get result from following query in a wordpress page?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I used this query in MySQL, that works fine. But how to execute this query in a Wordpress page?

```
SELECT COUNT(`wdt_ID`) AS eee
  FROM `ugdb_kpims`.`kpi_wpdatatable_3`
 WHERE CheckNull(q1) AND CURDATE() > '2019-03-31' 
   AND userid = 810
```

The result would be:

> ---
>
> ### eee
>
> ### 20

Comment: have you seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185734/how-do-i-run-a-mysql-query-in-wordpress/20185768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `wpdb` object to run the customized queries. Note you can get more info on [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), by clicking.

```
global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(wdt_ID) AS eee FROM ugdb_kpims.kpi_wpdatatable_3 WHERE CheckNull(q1) AND CURDATE() > '2019-03-31' AND userid = 810");
print_r($result);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please select the answer and upvote if its helps you to find the solution